# laravel routes. `action="{{'register'}}"` what does this code do

Tags: laravel, routes

I am new in Laravel coding, I have a problem in routing. I am using Laravel 5.5. this is the code that I need an explanation on what it does and how it works.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
```

This code is from the registration view. The form post username, name, password, token to the server.

I would like to know how the data is handled, and where the data is routed to, through the action `action="{{'register'}}"`.

Comment: have a look at this `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`

Comment: the registercontroller.php only has the create function and validate function. what exactly should i be looking at.

Comment: this controller uses a trait `RegistersUsers`, look at that trait has register function, which you are searching may be

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes):

> Named routes allow the convenient generation of URLs or redirects for specific routes. You may specify a name for a route by chaining the `name` method onto the route definition:

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    //
})->name('profile');
```

> You may also specify route names for controller actions:

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

> Once you have assigned a name to a given route, you may use the route's name when generating URLs or redirects via the global `route` function:

```
{{ route('profile') }}
```

Comment: my route.php file has `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('register');
});
` so how is the `action="{{'register'}}"` code running without any routes named register

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen `register` is a part of auth routes. Run `php artisan route:list` command to see all registered routes with their names.

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen when you use
{{ route('profile') }}
profile is your name inside route file like
Route::method('url','Controller/function')->name('profile')
Once you have assigned a name to a given route, you may use the route's name when generating URLs or redirects via the global route function: